# Getting VMware Port-ID using commandline

Tags: networking, virtualization, automation

Is there a way to directly gather the vmware port-id using commandline?

I'm trying to make monitoring switchports easy through esxcli but in order to get port statistics I require the portid of a VM which seems to be quite an involved operation using vMA (Virtual Machine Assistant)

Example below, I just want to easily be able to get portid by doing something like:

```
esxcli network portid (VMNAME)
```

But I cannot find anything similar to that.

```
esxcli network port stats get
Error: Missing required parameter -p|--portid

Usage: esxcli network port stats get [cmd options]

Description:
  get                   Packet statistics for a given port.

Cmd options:
  -p|--portid=    Port ID for the port to get statistics. (required)
```

Comment: What edition and licensing tier of VMware are you using?

Comment: @ewwhite VMware ESXi 5.1u1

Comment: Licensing? Are you using Essentials? Essentials Plus? Enterprise Plus?

Comment: @ewwhite sorry, i'm using "standard" forgot that detail :P

Answer (score 3):

I have tested the following on `ESXi 6.7u2`. It's possible to obtain the Port ID via the shell.  First obtain the World ID for your VM:

```
esxcli network vm list
```

Result:

```
World ID  Name     Num Ports  Networks
--------  -------  ---------  ----------
2102511  some_vm           1  some_net
```

Then:

```
esxcli network vm port list -w 2102511
```

Which gives you the `Port ID`.

[(source)](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vcli.examples.doc%2Fcli_manage_networks.11.4.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following link, I believe that is the command you are looking for.

http://www.vmwarearena.com/2014/03/esxi-query-network-hint-cdp-information-of-esxi-host-in-command-line.html